# How to add an one-hot layer in the middle of the Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have an autoencoder model
like this

```
    input_img = Input(shape=(132,))

    l1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_img)
    l2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(l1)
    l3 = Dense(nb_class)(l2)
    l_select = Activation("softmax")(l3)        
    l4 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(l_select)
    l5 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(l4)
    l6 = Dense(132, activation='relu')(l5)
    self.model_3 = Model(inputs=[input_img], output=l6)
```

and I want to insert an one-hot layer after the softmax layer
like this

```
    input_img = Input(shape=(132,))

    l1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_img)
    l2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(l1)
    l3 = Dense(nb_class)(l2)
    l_select = Activation("softmax")(l3)
    l7 = Lambda(K.round)(l_select)

    l4 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(l7)
    l5 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(l4)
    l6 = Dense(132, activation='relu')(l5)
    self.model_2 = Model(inputs=[input_img], output=l7)
    self.model_3 = Model(inputs=[input_img], output=l6)
```

I don't want any float into to my decode layer, I want a certain selection into the decode layer.

If I try to use K.argmax, K.round, it will output an error

```
     ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that 
     all of your ops have a gradient defined 
     (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, 
     K.round, K.eval.
```

Is there any way to insert an one-hot layer into the middle of the model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633257/10375049